# Conversational Actions quick start guide - failing

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

First timer here and I'm stuck :(

I'm trying to get a project of the ground by following the [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart). I've tried countless different ways of creating a project in the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/). I believe that it should be `New project -> Game -> Blank project (for smart display)`. I have enabled the [Actions API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/actions.googleapis.com) for that project.

I created the project like this `gactions init interactive-canvas --dest test-canvas`

I have updated the file `sdk/settings/settings.yaml` with my project ID.

When I try to push my project with `gactions push` I get a couple of warnings and especially this one `Custom actions can only be specified in Conversational Actions projects`:

```
...
Waiting for server to respond...
[WARNING] Server found validation issues (however, your files were still pushed):
  Locale  Validation Result
          Custom actions can only be specified in Conversational Actions projects.
  en      Short description is required
  en      Long description is required
...
```

When I try to run `gactions deploy preview` I get the following error:

```
Deploying files in the project "test-canvas" to Actions Console for preview. This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...
Sending resources...
Waiting for server to respond. It could take up to 1 minute if your cloud function needs to be redeployed.
[ERROR] Server did not return HTTP 200.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Custom actions can only be specified in Conversational Actions projects."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I create a `Conversational Actions project`? I thought that I was doing that all along? I am Confused. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Kind regards,
Tobias

```
$ gactions version
3.0.0+316143447
```

Comment: Same issue here. Deploying using `gactions push` or via the Deploy UI shows the same error: `Custom actions can only be specified in Conversational Actions projects.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying start up a project too. I get that same error message, and I'm wondering if it's something on Google's side that needs to be fixed. For now, I'm just using `gactions push` when I update any code and going to **Actions Console > Webhooks** and clicking on **Deploy**. I wait for it to deploy to the server then I click on the **Test** tab to play with the simulator.

Comment: You're correct. It seems like it was a temporary thing. It is now working as expected.

Comment: Don't think this was temporary, still not working for us :(